# Could not install create-react-app through npm

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app

I used the following code to install create-react-app

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

I am getting

```
error 500:
npm ERR! code E500
npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error: create-react-app@latest
```

Full error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'create-react-app' ]
2 info using npm@6.2.0
3 info using node@v10.9.0
4 verbose npm-session 6a3b73048c509207
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 500 http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app 70467ms attempt #3
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for create-react-app@latest 500 Internal Server Error: create-react-app@latest
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 2ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 71028ms
11 verbose stack Error: 500 Internal Server Error: create-react-app@latest
11 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
11 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
11 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
11 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:693:18)
11 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:664:5)
11 verbose stack     at processImmediate (timers.js:646:5)
12 verbose cwd E:\web-dev\node-js
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "create-react-app"
15 verbose node v10.9.0
16 verbose npm  v6.2.0
17 error code E500
18 error 500 Internal Server Error: create-react-app@latest
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have tried most error solving techniques like:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Also I uninstalled the node and installed latest version of Node 10.1. I also set the ssl to false, but that also didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

I run:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

and see:

```
+ create-react-app@1.5.2
added 67 packages from 20 contributors in 10.728s
```

Please try it again.

My recommendation is [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install)

It is faster than `npm`.

Comment: It was really wierd that npm servers were down on the day I encountered problem, on that day no npm install was working. I saw their server status and there was clearly a problem. Now it's working correctly.

Comment: Yes, status is `500` (server wrong, not you) so I said `Please try it again.`
Use `yarn` can't fixed that problem, but I think use `yarn` is better `npm`

Comment: I agree about using `yarn`.